# How to match entities with stored procedure results(ASP.Net MVC with entity framework)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am calling one stored procedure which will takes 5 inputs and will returns a set of table data. I have created the class to match with the stored procedure results. How to map this stored procedure result with class?

My stored procedure will takes 6 parameters like below

```
PROC_REZ_GETCHNAVL 7012,3,20130816,20130817,1,'INR'
```

and it will gives the table set which will exactly same as below table.

`public class AvailableRooms
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int CUSTCODE { get; set; }
        public int CHANNID { get; set; }
        public string RATECODE { get; set; }
        public int RUNSRLNUB { get; set; }
        public string ROOMTYPE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Room Name")]
        public string ROOMNAME { get; set; }
        public string ROOMSHTDESC { get; set; }
        public string ROOMLNGDESC { get; set; }
        public string ROOMFEATURES { get; set; }
        public int MAXADT { get; set; }
        public int MAXCHD { get; set; }
        public int TOTROM { get; set; }
        public char AVLFLG { get; set; }
        public int AVLROM { get; set; }
        public decimal OCCPER { get; set; }
        public string RATETYPE { get; set; }
        public string RATEPLAN { get; set; }
        public string RATEDESCRP { get; set; }
        public string RUNDAT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Room Rate")]
        public decimal SGLRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal DBLRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal TRPRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal QUDRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal ADTRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal CHDRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNSGLRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNDBLRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNTRPRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNQUDRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNEXTADTRAT { get; set; }
        public decimal PLNEXTCHDRAT { get; set; }
        public string ROOMIMG { get; set; }
        public string PRPSHORTDESC { get; set; }
        public string PRPLONGDESC { get; set; }
        public string PRPFEATURES { get; set; }
        public string TERMSCOND { get; set; }
        public string CACELPOLICY { get; set; }
        public string ROOMVID { get; set; }
        public string CHANNELDESC { get; set; }
        public int MAXPER { get; set; }
        public int EXTPER { get; set; }
        public int SEASONCODE { get; set; }
        private decimal _SGLTOTRATE;
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:##,###}")]
        public decimal SGLTOTRATE
        {
            get
            {
                return makeFormat(_SGLTOTRATE);
            }
            set
            {
                _SGLTOTRATE = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Room Rate Currency Format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_sglTotRate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private decimal makeFormat(decimal _sglTotRate)
        {
            if (_sglTotRate.ToString().Contains('.'))
                _sglTotRate = Convert.ToDecimal(_sglTotRate.ToString("G29"));
            return _sglTotRate;
        }
        public decimal DBLTOTRATE { get; set; }
        public decimal EXTADTTOT { get; set; }
        public decimal EXTCHDTOT { get; set; }
        public decimal RACKSGL { get; set; }
        public decimal RACKDBL { get; set; }
        public decimal RACKADT { get; set; }
        public decimal RACKCHD { get; set; }
        public string MEALTYPE { get; set; }
        public int DISSEQ { get; set; }
    }`

Please let me know how to map this class with stored procedure with DbContext?????

Awaiting for your resply.

Comment: What have you tried? have a look here to get you started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673

Comment: Hi Wheel, I have already looked into this examples and these are related to insert,update and delete operations. I have a specific requirement where my stored procedure returns a table set and i didnt find this in the same url which u have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution for this.

namespace WBE.Repository
{
    public class WBERepository : WBEContext,IWBERepository
    {

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get All the available rooms with respect to input parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="roomAvailInputs"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<RoomInventory> GetRoomInventory(List<InventoryInputs> roomAvailInputs)
    {

            using (var context = new WBEContext())
            {
                var CustCode = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.Int32,
                    ParameterName = "CSTCOD",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].CUSTCODE
                };

                var ChnlCode = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.Int32,
                    ParameterName = "CHNCOD",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].CHNCOD
                };

                var ArrDate = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    ParameterName = "ARRDAT",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].ARRDAT
                };
                var DepDate = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    ParameterName = "DEPDAT",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].DEPDAT
                };
                var NoRooms = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.Int32,
                    ParameterName = "NBROOM",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].NBROOM
                };

                var CurType = new SqlParameter
                {
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    ParameterName = "CURTYP",
                    Value = roomAvailInputs[0].CURTYP
                };

              return context.Database.SqlQuery<RoomInventory>
                                ("PROC_REZ_GETCHNAVL @CSTCOD, @CHNCOD,  @ARRDAT, @DEPDAT, @NBROOM, @CURTYP",
                                CustCode, ChnlCode, ArrDate, DepDate, NoRooms, CurType).ToList<RoomInventory>();
            }
```